# PayPal Recurring Payments Demo invalid profile description?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

Using this code: https://github.com/thenbrent/paypal-digital-goods-php-examples

PayPal Recurring Payments Demo

> Error: Calling PayPal with action CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile has
>   Failed: Profile description is invalid

How do I fix this / find out the cause of the error?

I'm really lost!

Comment: Please provide more information. What are you setting the profile description field to?

Comment: @SgtPooki I can't find such a field! I am wondering...this maybe because I am a standard (not pro) paypal customer!?

Comment: Express Checkout (the only product that currently has a 'digital goods' moniker) does not require anything other than a regular PayPal account. Your only problem is not defining the profile description field.